# How do I loop column names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and have never really used Pandas, so forgive me if this doesn't make sense. I am trying to create a df based on frontend data I am sending to a flask route. The data is looped through and appended for each row. My only problem is that I don't know how to get the df columns to reflect that. Here is my code to build the rows and the current output:

```
claims = csv_data["claims"]
setups = csv_data["setups"]
for setup in setups:
  setup = setups[0]
  offerings = setup["currentOfferings"]
  considered = setup["considerationSet"]
  reach_dict = setup["reach"]
  favorite_dict = setup["favorite"]
  summary_dict = setup["summaryMetrics"]


rows = []
for i, claim in enumerate(claims):
  row = []
  row.append(i + 1)
  row.append(claim)
  for setup in setups:
    setup = setups[0]
    row.append("X") if claim in setup["currentOfferings"] else row.append(float('nan'))
    row.append("X") if claim in setup["considerationSet"] else row.append(float('nan'))
    if claim in setup["currentOfferings"]:
      reach_score = reach_dict[claim]
      reach_percentage = "{:.0%}".format(reach_score)
      row.append(reach_percentage)
    else:
      row.append(float('nan'))
    if claim in setup["currentOfferings"]:
      favorite_score = favorite_dict[claim]
      fav_percentage = "{:.0%}".format(favorite_score)
      row.append(fav_percentage)
    else:
      row.append(float('nan'))

  rows.append(row)
```

[image: output]
I know that I can put columns = ["#", "Claims", "Setups", etc...] in the df, but that doesn't work because the rows are looping through multiple setups, and the number of setups can change. If I don't specify the column names (how it is in the image), then I just have numbers as columns names. Ideally it should loop through the data it receives in the route, and would start with "#" "Claims" as columns, and then for each setup "Setup 1", "Consideration Set 1", "Reach", "Favorite", "Setup 2", "Consideration Set 2", and so on... etc.

I tried to create a similar type of loop for the columns:

```
my_columns = []
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
  col = []
  if row[0] != None:
    col.append("#")
  else:
    pass
  if row[1] != None:
    col.append("Claims")
  else:
    pass
  if row[2] != None:
    col.append("Setup")
  else:
    pass
  if row[3] != None:
    col.append("Consideration Set")
  else:
    pass
  if row[4] != None:
    col.append("Reach")
  else:
    pass
  if row[5] != None:
    col.append("Favorite")
  else:
    pass

my_columns.append(col)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    rows,
    columns = my_columns
    )
```

But this didn't work because I have the same issue of no loop, I have 6 columns passed and 10 data columns passed. I'm not sure if I am just not doing the loop of the columns properly, or if I am making everything more complicated than it needs to be.

This is what I am trying to accomplish without having to explicitly name the columns because this is just sample data. There could end up being 3, 4, however many setups in the actual app.
[what I would like the ouput to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dV2n.jpg)

Comment: could you add an example df of your desired output with the right column names ?

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing something like this but I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
def create_columns(df):
    new_cols=[]
    for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        repeated_cols = 6 #here is the number of columns you need to repeat for every setup
        idx = 1 + i // repeated_cols 
        basic = ['#', 'Claims', f'Setup_{idx}', f'Consideration_Set_{idx}', 'Reach', 'Favorite']
        new_cols.append(basic[i % len(basic)])
    return new_cols
    
df.columns = create_columns(df)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your data comes as csv then try pd.read_csv() to create dataframe.

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot I had named my variable csv_data, I see how that is confusing. The data being sent to the flask route is coming from a React table, not directly from a csv file. But I am trying to create a csv from the data, that's just poor naming on my part.